# Jquery autocomplete issue

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have an issue with my Jquery autocomplete code, if I use a declared VAR it works, if I take the same data from the inner html of a div it does not.

Here is the html

```
<div id="search_data">
['animal','alison','App','apple','apricot','tennis','terrible']
</div>

<input id="Text2" type="text" />

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
//This option works
var tags = ['c++', 'java', 'php', 'coldfusion', 'javascript', 'asp', 
'ruby'];

//This does not, but why?       
var newdata = document.getElementById("search_data").innerHTML

$("#Text2").autocomplete({
source: newdata
 });
```

Here is the issue on JSFiddle

[JS fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/pw_2002uk/d61b1swL/2/)

Comment: Because when you pick the data from the div, it is passed as a string!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead

```js
   
   //This option works
   var tags = ['c++', 'java', 'php', 'coldfusion', 'javascript', 'asp', 'ruby'];

  //This does not, but why?  
    var temp = [];
     
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("a");

    for(var i = 0; i< span.length; i++)
    {
     temp.push(span[i].innerHTML);
    }
$("#Text2").autocomplete({
source: temp
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search_data">
  ['animal','alison','App','apple','apricot','tennis','terrible']
  <span class="a">animal</span>
  <span class="a">alison</span>
  <span class="a">App</span>
  <span class="a">apple</span>
  <span class="a">apricot</span>
  <span class="a">tennis</span>
   <span class="a">terrible</span>
</div>

<input id="Text2" type="text" />

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Many thanks for this, I had a feeling the text sting issue was going to raise its head. The above answer helps me move forward, but the above was only a simplification of the actual issue. In reality there will be up to 100 items in the DIV, and as they come from a database, I can't be sure in advance what they will be. I guess I will now have to look at a way of automating the above process. to fill the temp variable with the items, and add the same class to all. If you have any thoughts on that it would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you using for backend?

Comment: ASP.net. - I was thinking about passing the data into a hidden Div, from the back end and using that data for the drop down list option. Passing it as a list of comma delimited names (that's the list, names), looks possible. There will only be about 60.

Answer (score 0):

With a push in the right direction from Ali I have solved my problem.

```
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div id="search_data1">
animal,alison,App,apple,apricot,tennis,terrible
</div>

<input id="Text2" type="text" />

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>



var newspan = document.getElementById("search_data1").innerHTML

var array = newspan.split(",")

$("#Text2").autocomplete({
source: array
});
```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/pw_2002uk/d61b1swL/